# Find total data size uploaded to CKAN

Tags: ckan

I am new to CKAN, I have uploaded a large number of file to CKAN through GUI. Now, I want to find total size of all the files uploaded to CKAN. I have searched for it, but did not find any relevant data.

Is there any way to find total size of data uploaded to ckan? or is there any extension through which we can get this information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific page where you can preview this information but you can check the FileStore location storage size if you have FileStore enabled. To find the location of the filestore check the .ini file for `ckan.storage_path` location e.g `/var/lib/ckan/default`